# My client won't reload after ajax put even with .then and location.reload

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can't get the client to console.log or reload after this ajax PUT. The put goes through to the database fine. I just need it to reload to see the new results.

```
$(".devour").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = { id: $(this).attr("id") };

  $.ajax("/", {
    type: "PUT",
    data: id,
  }).then(function() {
    console.log("Updated Burger");
    location.reload();
  });
});
```

Comment: try catching the promise to see if it is indeed reaching then part or failing before that

Comment: You should always assume that an ajax call can fail, and because of that you should handle the error at the end of the promise chain. What does the console show if you add `.catch(function(err) { console.dir(err)})` ? Beside that the network tab in the developer tools of your browser should also tell you what error is reported.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm pretty new to this so I haven't leaned about Promises or .catch yet. I can see the Put go through in the Network portion of the Debugger but that's all I got at this point. Thank you for the suggestions though. There is no error in the Network portion of the Debugger. The PUT goes through and all, but the page doesn't reload after

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: 'http://example.com/api',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data), // access in body
    })
    .then( 
          ()=>console.log("success"),
          ()=>console.log("FAIL"));//check for fail may be issue 

or try more explicit order way 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: 'http://example.com/api',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data), // access in body
    }).done(function () {
        console.log('SUCCESS');
    }).fail(function (msg) {
        console.log('FAIL');
    }).always(function (msg) {
        console.log('ALWAYS');
    });
```

Comment: Why do you recommend the old API which is not Promise/A+ compatible, although the OP already uses `.then`?

Comment: @t.niese - i recommended to find out that its working orlder way or not because its true code is ok there is no problem with it